# How to overload "operator new" with custom malloc to make it call the constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, operator-overloading, malloc

I'd written my `malloc` implementation (let it called `mymalloc(size_t)`) that gathers additional information and saves it to the list. Now I need to overload `operator new` to make it work with `mymalloc(size_t)`, not `malloc(size_t)`. In VS2010 I found this implementation of `operator new`:

```
void *__CRTDECL operator new(size_t size) _THROW1(_STD bad_alloc)
{       // try to allocate size bytes
    void *p;
    while ((p = malloc(size)) == 0)
        if (_callnewh(size) == 0)
        {       // report no memory
             static const std::bad_alloc nomem;
             _RAISE(nomem);
        }

        return (p);
}
```

See: there's no `placement new` in this code! Then my question is: How to overload `operator new` with `mymalloc` as memory allocation function to make it call the constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The job of `operator new()` (and `operator new[]()`) is to provide a pointer to memory where an object can be constructed. These operators do **not** call any constructor for the object which is being constructed. In fact, they can't even know the exact type for which memory is allocated: even if a class-specific `operator new()` is overloaded, it will be used with derived types, as well.

Note that you also need to overload/replace the corresponding `operator delete()` and `operator delete[]()`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do something to invoke the constructor, it will be called and your `new` should just take care about memory. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dd4f166afbea87f):

```
struct A
{
    void* operator new(size_t);
    //void operator delete(void*);

    A()
    {
        cout << "Constuctor is called" << endl;
    }
};

void* A::operator new(size_t size)
{
    cout << "New new is called" << endl;
    void *storage = malloc(size);
    if(0 == storage)
    {
        throw "allocation fail : no free memory";
    }
    return storage;
}

int main()
{
     new A;
}
```

Output

> New new is called
>
> Constuctor is called

Comment: Wow. Is that means that each `new` overload will automatically call the constructor? It's not apparent for me because I can manually call the destructor, but not the constructor.

Comment: Overloading `new` and `delete` you should not call constructor and destructor. Just manage the allocated memory. [_Here_](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_new.html) is a good explanation.

Comment: @RomanChehowsky I think you're getting into a confusing between `operator new` and `new X`. Calling `new X` first calls `operator new` to allocate memory. After the storage has been allocated, it calls the constructor for `X` using that allocated storage as its location. You can't change the behavior of `new X`, but you can control `operator new`.